# Getting some unknown error in my script

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, summernote

I m making a web app in adv java and using many external libraries like choosen.js summernote.js bootstrap bootstrapValidator etc.. Now I getting some error and I now able to find which is causing all these errors.If anybody know anything related about this please help me
[image: Error shown in the image]

please help me find the solution.

code of summernote

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.summernote').summernote({
       height:270,
        minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true,


    });
});
```

**all the libraries that I am using**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spinnaker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/adminstyles.css">



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js">     </script>




<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.0/summernote.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/assets/js/myscripts.js"></script>
```

**my ajax calling code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#side-menu li").click(function (event) {
      var link = $(this).attr('id');

    switch (link) {
        case 'dash':
            $.get("ajaxpages/dashboard.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data);

            });

            break;
        case 'info':
            $.get("ajaxpages/info.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data);


            });



            break;
        case 'sms':
            $.get("ajaxpages/sms.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
            });


            break;
        case 'email':
            $.get("ajaxpages/email.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data).fadeIn("slow");

            });



            break;
        case 'achievements':
            $.get("ajaxpages/achievements.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data);

            });
            break;
        case 'test':
            $.get("ajaxpages/questions.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data);

            });



            break;
        case 'profile':
            $.get("ajaxpages/settings.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data);

            });



            break;
        default:
            $.get("ajaxpages/dashboard.jsp", function (data) {
                $("#contentLoader").html(data);

            });
    }

  });
});


**choosen library code**
     $(document).ready(function () {
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-deselect': {allow_single_deselect: true},
        '.chosen-select-no-single': {disable_search_threshold: 10},
        '.chosen-select-no-result': {no_results_text:'Oops,nothing fund!'},
        '.chosen-select-width':{width:'95%'}


    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }


});
```

**bootstrapValidator**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("email-form validation");

    var validator = $("#email-form").bootstrapValidator({
        live:'enabled',
        message:'This value is not valid',
        submitButton:'$email-form button[type="submit]',
        submitHandler:function(validatior,form,submitButton){
            $.ajax({

                url: "../../MailDispatcherServlet",
                method: "post",
                data: $('#email-form').serialize(),
                dataType: "String",

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#message_show').text("success");

                    $("#email-form").data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

                    alert("hiiiiii");
                    console.log("hiiiii");

                    $("#email-form")[0].reset();
                }

            });
            return false;




        },

        fields: {
            email: {
                message: "Email is required",
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: "Please provide an email address"
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 35,
                        message: "Email must be between 6 and 35 characters long"
                    },

                    emailAddress: {
                        message: "Email address must be valid"
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                        message: 'Not a valid email address'
                    }

                }
            }, //.email
            subject: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Content is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'Must be more than 6 and less than 500 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/,
                        message: 'The title can only consist of alphabetical number and spaces'
                    }
                }
            },
            message: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Content is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 3000,
                        message: 'Must be more than 0 and less than 5000 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/,
                        message: 'The title can only consist of alphabetical number and spaces'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any code it is hard to help, but judging from the error, it looks like you have a typo when you are calling this function or it is not included in the library you are working with.

Comment: i have included all the libraries as per my knowledge .. actually it works for few minutes then after that it shows some error. i m loading all the pages with ajax so clicking the links first load the pages as desired but after some time it shows error and everything stop working

Comment: Do you have any code that you could possibly include?

Comment: sure but which code to upload.  I m adding the code where i m incluing summernote.

Comment: Include the code in which the error is coming from and where you are including libraries.

Comment: i have included all the libraries and my javascript code